# SwiftUI JSON to Picker

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am trying to get the "roles" to display as the text in a Picker. When I just use a generic Text view inside the Picker it will display 5 times like it is supposed to, but I can't seem to pull the name from the struct.

JSON Data:

```
[
{"roles": "Gorilla",
"index": 0},
{"roles": "Armadillo",
"index": 1},
{"roles": "Cheetah",
"index": 2},
{"roles": "Iguana",
"index": 3},
{"roles": "Monkey",
"index": 4}
]
```

Model:

```
import Foundation

struct inviteModel: Codable, Identifiable{
    
    let id = UUID()
    var roles:String
    var index:Int
    
}
```

View:

```
@State var roleList = [inviteModel]()

 private func loadRoles(){
        
        Task {
            
            var ackval = "58ikf0"

            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "MYURL")!)
            
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let parameters = "ack=\(ackVal)"
            request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
            
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request as URLRequest)
            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 {
                    
                do{
                    self.roleList = try JSONDecoder().decode([inviteModel].self, from: data)
                    }catch{
                    print(error)
                    }
                
                
            } else {
                print("API Error")
            }
            isSending = false
        }
        
    }

Picker(selection: $role1, label: Text("Role 1")) {
    ForEach(0..<roleList.count, id: \.self) { rlist in
        Text(rlist.roles).tag(0)
    }                                                
}
```

Im sure its probably something simple but I am new to Swift.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE: I found the answer by looking at the code above that was provided.

```
Picker(selection: $role1, label: Text("Role 1")) {
    ForEach(roleList) { role in
        Text("\(role.roles)").tag(role.index)
    }
                                                            
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, where you use the roles selection `role1` to be the **same type** as the `Picker` items `.tag()`.

```
struct InviteModel: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {  // <-- here
    let id = UUID()
    var roles:String
    var index:Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var role1 = "Gorilla" // <-- here
    @State var roleList = [InviteModel]()
    
    private func loadRoles(){
        // for testing
        roleList = [InviteModel(roles: "Gorilla", index: 0),
                         InviteModel(roles: "Armadillo", index: 1),
                         InviteModel(roles: "Cheetah", index: 2),
                         InviteModel(roles: "Iguana", index: 3),
                         InviteModel(roles: "Monkey", index: 4)]
//        Task {
//            var ackval = "58ikf0"
//            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "MYURL")!)
//            request.httpMethod = "POST"
//            let parameters = "ack=\(ackVal)"
//            request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
//            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request as URLRequest)
//            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 {
//                do{
//                    self.roleList = try JSONDecoder().decode([inviteModel].self, from: data)
//                }catch{
//                    print(error)
//                }
//            } else {
//                print("API Error")
//            }
//            isSending = false
//        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Role 1", selection: $role1) {
            ForEach(roleList) { invite in
                Text(invite.roles).tag(invite.roles)  // <-- here
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadRoles()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One important teaching here is how to isolate a problem.

Comment: this isn't quite the answer, although it did show me how to fix the problem

Comment: ok, what did not work with my answer? What I show is an approach to use the Picker `.tag(...)`. You can of course put the `index` in this `.tag()`, as you have done, as long as it is of the **same type** as the selection `role1` like I describe in my answer.